# S22.Imap Attachment Count Always Return 0

Tags: c#, imap, email-attachments, gmail-imap

I am trying to download an email attachment from an email stored in my Gmail inbox. Using the S22.Imap lib (https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap) I get the list of messages and then iterate over them to download the attachments. The problem I have is that the MailMessage.Attachments.Count is always 0, even when there is definitely a file attached. Here is my code to download the attachments.

```
            foreach (MailMessage m in messages)
            {
                if(m.Subject.Contains("Activity Statement") && (m.Attachments.Count > 0))
                {
                    foreach (Attachment a in m.Attachments)
                    {
                        var fileStream = File.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.ETL_ATTACHMENT_PROCESSING_DIR + a.Name);
                        a.ContentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        a.ContentStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go.. `Net.Mail.Attachment.ContentStream` will give you a stream you can copy to a file. To check the size, use `ContentStream.Length`

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
{
    byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.ContentStream.Length];
    int bytesRead = attachment.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.ContentStream.Length);
    string destinationFile = @"C:\\Path\\" + attachment.Name;
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));
    writer.Write(allBytes);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: message.Attachments is always empty so my attachment saving code never runs. Even when there is definitely an attachment in the message it doesn't seem to pick it up. Perhaps I don't fully understand the makeup of an imap message?

Comment: Regarding attachment status: Some bodyparts are declared to be attachments, some are declared not to be, but many (perhaps most) aren't declared, and classification is up to the reader. S22 and you may well disagree about how to classify something. If S22 makes an attempt at all. I suspect Mailkit will agree more with you.

Comment: He did say `message.Attachments` returns nothing so how is this answer useful? Your  loop will still not run